# Slow JNI-based Spark job on EC2

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, java-native-interface

I am calling native JNI-based functions in Map operations of Spark.

```
// Read each input from HDFS or S3
val A = info.sc.broadcast(fs.read(0, 4)) // 400 MB
val B = info.sc.broadcast(fs.read(1, 4)) // 400 MB

// Generate RDD
val index = info.sc.parallelize(0.toLong to SIZE-1 by 1)

// Perform Map operations --> the problematic part
val res = index.map{ x => nativeFunction(x, A, B) }.persist

// Fake action for profiling purpose
res.foreachPartition{ x =>  } 

// Get the results back and write them in the HDFS or S3
val output = res.reduce(Util.bitor)
fs.write(2, output)
```

When I am running it on EC2, the execution of the mapping takes about 4x more than when I run it on a local cluster with the same partitionning and number of cores.

When I run the native function outside of Spark, the execution is equivalent which proves that is not because of EC2 virtualization.

Any idea of a reason ?

Comment: I just discovered the problem doesn't occur if I set-up Spark by hand  (i.e. without spark-ec2 script) on EC2 using ubuntu 14.04 ami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was too change to a more recent linux image